# Spotify selenium follow

Tags: python, selenium

Im trying to click a follow button on a spotify page with selenium but it wont work.

My code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from colorama import init,Fore,Style
import time

driver: WebDriver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login?continue=https"

follow = "https://open.spotify.com/user/yrhi1k9idyhrx7u8g2wqki1bl?si=aeaa719645654775"
us = open("username.txt", "r")
pw = open("password.txt", "r")

for i in range(3000):
    a = us.readline()

    b = pw.readline()

    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_id("login-username").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("login-username").send_keys(a)
    driver.find_element_by_id("login-password").send_keys(b)
    driver.find_element_by_id("login-button").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.get(follow)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Takip Et']"))).click()    
    time.sleep(2)
us.close()
pw.close()
driver.close()
```

Error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "\spotifyLoginBotDemo.py", line 29, in 
> wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Follow']"))).click()
> File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide us with a link to web page you are working on.

Comment: im trying to follow user on spotify with this link https://open.spotify.com/user/yrhi1k9idyhrx7u8g2wqki1bl

Comment: Which are the steps you are executing from your code? You need to be logged in order to follow someone on Spotify. Share your code to have a proper image of your issue.

Comment: I added the whole code